# JQuery шаблонизатор возвращает строку вместо html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

[Symfony3, twgig - template]
return x; - постоянно возвращает строку типа `"<span>710</span>₽<div><span>319.5000</span>₽</div>"`, а мне нужен html, теги для генерации контента, как я могу их отрендерить?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function searchCertificateAction() {
                var template =
                        "<div class='pr-one'>" +

                        "<div class='img'>" +
                        "<img title='${name}' src='${image}'>" +
                        "</div>" +

                        "<div class='pr-name'>" +
                        "${name}" +
                        "</div>" +

                        "<div class='price sale-price'>"+ "${price_result}"+ "</div>" +

                        "<div class='pay'><span>В корзину</span></div>" +   

                        "</div>";

                var empty = "<p>No response...</p>";

                $("#certificate_search_certificate input[type = 'submit']").on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: $('#certificate_search_certificate').serialize(),
                        url: '{{ path("app.client.catalog", {"category_parent": 'all', "category_children": 'all'}) }}',
                        success: function (data) {
                            var dataParse = JSON.parse(data.certificate_response);
                            var resultHtml = "#products";
                            $(resultHtml).empty();
                            if (dataParse.length !== 0) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < dataParse.length; i++) {
                                    $.tmpl(template, {
                                        "id": dataParse[i].id,
                                        "name": dataParse[i].name,
                                        "price": dataParse[i].price,
                                        "image": dataParse[i].image,
                                        "total_price": dataParse[i].total_price,
                                        "price_result": function (total_price = dataParse[i].total_price, price = dataParse[i].price) {
                                            if (total_price === undefined) {
                                                var x = "<div><span>" + price + "</span>₽</div>";
                                                return x;
                                            } else {
                                                var x = "<span>" + price + "</span>₽<div><span>" + total_price + "</span>₽</div>";
                                                return x;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }).appendTo(resultHtml);
                                }
                            } else {
                                $.tmpl(empty, {}).appendTo(resultHtml);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
            searchCertificateAction();
        </script>
```

Comment: а строка типа `"<span>710</span>₽<div><span>319.5000</span>₽</div>"` это не html что ли?

Comment: оно так и выводиться в html, только вместо <> - кракозябры.

Comment: кракозябры это `&gt;` и `&lt;` ? :) что за `$.tmpl()` функция-то у вас?

Comment: если у вас там используется древний `jquery templates` то вроде в шаблоне можно прописать не `${price_result}` а `{{html price_result}}`, проверьте, если что оформлю ответом.

Comment: да, древний jQuery =), я не могу использовать "{{ }}", так как использую шаблонизатор twig.
Так я обращаюсь к своему екшену на бекенде `{{ path("app.client.catalog", {"category_parent": 'all', "category_children": 'all'}) }}`

Comment: ну скобки в твиге тоже ведь можно вывести в виде `{{ '{{' }}`, то есть в тексте тогда должно быть `{{ '{{' }}html price_result{{ '}}' }}`, на выходе из твига получите, приведенную выше строку

Comment: ухты, сейчас попробую

Comment: не зашло такое решение:                        
 `"{{ '{{' }}"+ "if ${price_status}"+ "{{ '}}' }}" +
                        "<div><span> ${price}</span>₽</div>" +
                        "{{ '{{' }}" + "else" +  "{{ '}}' }}" +
                        "<span> ${price} </span>₽<div><span> ${total_price} </span>₽</div>" +
                        "{{ '{{' }}"+ "/if"+ "{{ '}}' }}" +`

Comment: зачем вам вообще плюсы в этом выражении были? тут все вхождения `" + "` удалить надо

Comment: вообще надо было весь код js-шаблона заключить в twig-теги `{% verbatim %}` или `{% raw %}` в зависимости от версии твига. То что внутри - не обрабатывается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, может не самое лучшее но других я не вижу (в данный момент). Добавил проверку перед рендерингом шаблона в которой выбирается нужный Шаблон.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function searchCertificateAction() {

                    var template_true =
                            "<p>true</p>" +
                            "<div class='pr-one'>" +

                            "<div class='img'>" +
                            "<img title='${name}' src='${image}'>" +
                            "</div>" +

                            "<div class='pr-name'>" +
                            "${name}" +
                            "</div>" +

                            "<div class='price sale-price'>" +
                            "<div><span>" + " ${price} " + "</span>₽</div>" +
                            "</div>" +

                            "<div class='pay'><span>В корзину</span></div>" +

                            "</div>";

                    var template_false =
                            "<p>false</p>" +
                            "<div class='pr-one'>" +

                            "<div class='img'>" +
                            "<img title='${name}' src='${image}'>" +
                            "</div>" +

                            "<div class='pr-name'>" +
                            "${name}" +
                            "</div>" +

                            "<div class='price sale-price'>" +
                            "<span>" + "${price}" + "</span>₽<div><span>" + "${total_price}" + "</span>₽</div>" +
                            "</div>" +

                            "<div class='pay'><span>В корзину</span></div>" +

                            "</div>";

                    var empty = "<p>No response...</p>";

                    $("#certificate_search_certificate input[type = 'submit']").on('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: $('#certificate_search_certificate').serialize(),
                            url: '{{ path("app.client.catalog", {"category_parent": 'all', "category_children": 'all'}) }}',
                            success: function (data) {
                                var dataParse = JSON.parse(data.certificate_response);
                                var resultHtml = "#products";
                                $(resultHtml).empty();

                                if (dataParse.length !== 0) {
                                    for (var i = 0; i < dataParse.length; i++) {

                                        var template;
                                        if (dataParse[i].total_price === undefined) {
                                            template = template_true;
                                        } else {
                                            template = template_false;
                                        }

                                        $.tmpl(template, {
                                            "id": dataParse[i].id,
                                            "name": dataParse[i].name,
                                            "price": dataParse[i].price,
                                            "image": dataParse[i].image,
                                            "total_price": dataParse[i].total_price,
                                        }).appendTo(resultHtml);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $.tmpl(empty, {}).appendTo(resultHtml);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
                searchCertificateAction();
            </script>
```